# How can i map an array starting from the end of the array to the beginning?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to map an Array but I don't want to start the iteration from the beginning index. I want to start mapping the Array from the last index of the array and go all the way to the beginning descending.

How can I do this in JavaScript ? Is there an easy way that JS provides or something I missed?

Comment: `.reverse()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: Notice that `Array.prototype.reverse()` change the original array in place, 
another option is to use `Array.prototype.reduceRight()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use the .reverse() method before mapping. Here is an example:

```
const array = ["one", "two", "three"];

const reversedMap = [...array].reverse().map(x => {
  return x;
});
```

> **This will return ["three", "two", "one"]**

You can of course map it however u want, if you for example wanted an unordered list you would do something like this:

```
const array = ["one", "two", "three"];

const reversed = [...array].reverse().map(x => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>{x}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
});
```